# The best way to count score in iOS Game

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently making a "rock, paper, scissors" game for iOS using cocos2d, and and wondering what is the best way to count and pass score across each scene gracefully and efficiently. The Score would hold 3 values(wins,losses,draws), therefore most likely be an array.

The game consists of three scenes, menu, pick your sign, and result scene (w/l/d)
i want to be able to display the scores on all three.

Comment: What have u tried so far? There is no 'best way', the easiest  and most comfortable way is the best way for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is a gud option to save score locally -

To save use -

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:SCORE forKey:@"Scores"];
```

To get Score on any scene -

```
scores = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Scores"];
```

Make different keys for wins,losses,draws. or you can save array with wins,losses,draws under a single key.

Answer (score 0):

The score is part of the global "game" object and is not part of the scene, so I would create a `Game` object and use the singleton pattern so that only one instance of the object exists within the process.

This `Game` class can then do what it likes to communicate/serialize its state using `NSUserDefaults` or Game Center.

Comment: please don't use singleton pattern. this is not a valid case to use it.

Comment: @BryanChen Why not; seems like the ideal use of it.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37249/the-singleton-pattern/37259#37259 and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/252/when-is-singleton-appropriate

Comment: @BryanChen That answer appears to be arguing that using a singleton pattern for the `Game` object is correct, not incorrect.

Comment: I have developed games before and it's quite a common pattern to use to store game data, granted if he is only wanting to store a single score it is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to make the Game object itself a singleton; ideally you would instantiate it on "New Game" or "Start", and the instance would cease to exist sometime after "Game Over".

If you need it to persist across several scenes, you could have a global "GameManager" (this one, yes, a singleton) object with a property called something like `currentGame` that would always hold the game instance being currently played (or `nil` if not playing), and query that from each scene.

Just one approach; it all really depends on the design and structure of your game in particular.

Comment: How many games can be running at once that they need managing?

Comment: Usually one. But the game object is a model object, and it needs to have a clear lifetime, beginning and end. This is why I don't recommend a singleton for it. But of course, it's just a matter of opinion in design.

Comment: No; you can simply add a `reset` method when a new game is about to start.  There is no need for two objects, one of which does next-to-nothing.

Comment: Like I said, it's a matter of preference. Also, I don't think it is a matter of "how many instances there can be" at a given time what justifies the use of a dedicated Manager or not. Rather, to put control of the Game object as a resource (creation, access) in one hand.

Comment: Also, this pattern scales to the hypothetical case where more than one Game instance may be needed (e.g., store saved games, etc.).